# How do I convert a PEM cert to a PKCS12 with GnuTLS

Tags: ssl, openssl, gnutls

I want to use GnuTLS certtool to convert a PEM public and private key to a PKCS12 pfx bundle. I don't have openssl available to me on the target system. The equivalent command with openssl is:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

Comment: If the target runs on Windows, try Cygwin, it will give you access to openssl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ certtool --load-certificate certificate.pem --load-privkey certificate.pem --to-p12 --outder --outfile certificate.pfx
```